# GIT Find the history of commits on a branch across repo

Tags: git, github

I work on multiple repositories(say repo-1, repo-2, repo-3)  and all the repositories have common branch names (branch-1, branch-2, branch-3). Is there a way to find the history of commits to branch-1 on all repositories between 'commit-A'(on repo-1, branch-1) and 'commit-E' (on repo-3, branch-1).

Comment: Are the repositories related? Meaning are they forks?

Comment: This is interesting [repo](https://github.com/dreamyguy/gitlogg), it may be useful.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen yes. The repositories are related.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in any git repo. But in order to keep everything clean and clear, let's do it in a temporary repo.

```
git init temp
cd temp
#If you have already known exactly the sha1 values of commit_A and commit_E, 
#":repo1" and ":repo3" in the following two commands can be omitted.
git fetch <repo1_url> branch_1:repo1
git fetch <repo3_url> branch_1:repo3
#If you haven't, find them out first.

#History between commit-A and commit-E is ambiguous.
#It may have three different meanings:
#1.History of commits that are reachable from commit_A but not reachable from commit_E
git log commit_E..commit_A

#2.History of commits that are reachable from commit_E but not reachable from commit_A
git log commit_A..commit_E

#3.History of commits that are either reachable from commit_A or reachable from commit_E, 
#but not reachable from both at the sam time.
git log commit_A...commit_E
#or
git log commit_E...commit_A

#Finally remove the temporary repo.
cd ..
rm -rf temp
```